# Allow end users to change settings of a widget

Tags: widgets

I currently have a customized widget installed. At this moment, I would like to allow end users, through the use of certain admin menu (other than appearance menu) to change the settings for this widget. I thought there might be good widget API resources but it seems that widget API resources are pretty lacking. Can anyone tell me how I might be able to allow users to change settings via admin page instead of the widget page?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that there is no such thing as a "per user widget"? If one user would change a widgets setting in the DB (via some UI), then the widget settings would change for everybody. And then there's the problem that multiple users could change the data at the same time. Please explain **why** you want to do it that way - in an [edit]. It could be that you are facing a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: okay the reason is that the end user is likely the admin (so only one user or multiple users with that admin privilege) but he does not have the privilege to access appearance button. As such, there must be some functionality to change the settings. So technically he should be safe from the problem you have depicted.

Comment: Again: Additional information in an [edit], please.